# Search string from large amount of data(millions of record in CSV file)

Tags: sql-server, large-data

I have millions of record in csv file and i need to do string comparison and show the filtered record in Bootstrap data table.
CSV files are updated on daily basis with millions of record.

Note:
If i import csv file into sql database and apply search query in table to get the result, it takes a lot of time.

Can i do search from csv file without importing it in SQL?
If there any specific method/way to store data?
Is there any tools for text search or it can be done in MS SQL?
Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is likely too broad to be a good fit for what we normally accept as a valid question on SO. You're essentially asking "how can I find text in a file" and we could come up with 100 different ways, none of which are valid to you. I suggest you work on improving the performance of the db search, read up on indexing/full text searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OPENROWSET` to read your `CSV` file directly in SQL Server

You will need "Ad Hoc Distributed Queries" enabled:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Then you define the datasource this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Text;Database=C:\Temp\;IMEX=1;', -- the path to csv file
    [data_file#csv] -- csv file name, please note # instead of dot
) as t
```

If your file is a real CSV (comma separated) then it should work with default settings.

If your file is not a real CSV (comma separated) you can define your own file format just placing a file named "`SCHEMA.INI`" in the same folder of the csv file.

This schema.ini file must contains a section with the definition of the structure of your data file. (see details here [Schema.ini File (Text File Driver)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Example:

```
[data_file.csv]
Format=Delimited(;)
DecimalSymbol=.
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=10
Col1=ID Long
Col2=DESCR  char width 4
Col3=FIELD_X  char width 255
Col4=FIELD_Y  DateTime
...
...
Coln=aFieldName aDataType aWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can i do search from csv file without importing it in SQL?

Yes, there are many ways. If you're on Windows you can use command prompt `find` command. `find "string to find" C:\Windows\file.csv`

> If there any specific method/way to store data?

Depends what you need to do with your matches. What do you need to do with your results?

> Is there any tools for text search or it can be done in MS SQL?

Yes to both. A Database *may* not be the best place to store the data if it's not relational. If you need to find specific patterns in these text files then have a look at regex.

Comment: Can i do search in csv using sql query without importing it in sql?

Comment: Yes, you can use SQL to search for text without importing the data first. See @MtwStark's post for how to do this. The full documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)